# Debian Ethernet desapareció al actualizar Kernel

Tags: linux, debian, controller

Luego de hacer una actualización de todo mi sistema y entre ella actualizar el *Kernel*, dejó de funcionar el puerto *Ethernet* y solo puedo conectarme por *WiFi*. Cuando hago un `LSPCI` no lista ningún dispositivo que contenga  *Ethernet* y si miro **/etc/network/interfaces** no aparece **eth0**, solo aparece **lo**.

La información que tengo es la siguiente:

```
~$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Kernel:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux innovation 4.9.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.13-1 (2017-02-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Dispositivos:

```
~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 48)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal PRO [Radeon R7 M260]
05:00.0 SATA controller: Lite-On Technology Corporation Device 0224 (rev 10)
```

Módulos:

```
~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  2
ctr                    16384  4
ccm                    20480  2
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               454656  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
arc4                   16384  2
iwlmvm                245760  0
mac80211              667648  1 iwlmvm
amdkfd                139264  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             192512  0
radeon               1482752  1
kvm                   589824  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
iwlwifi               147456  1 iwlmvm
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
cfg80211              589824  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ttm                    98304  1 radeon
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
intel_cstate           16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
hid_plantronics        16384  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
joydev                 20480  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
fuse                   98304  3
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   122880  3 hid_generic,usbhid,hid_plantronics
snd_usb_audio         180224  4
snd_usbmidi_lib        28672  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_rawmidi
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             552960  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
rfkill                 24576  8 bluetooth,hp_wmi,cfg80211
intel_uncore          118784  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
evdev                  24576  21
serio_raw              16384  0
sg                     32768  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
tpm_infineon           20480  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 36864  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
i915                 1232896  23
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi
snd_hda_intel          36864  8
battery                16384  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
drm_kms_helper        155648  2 radeon,i915
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_pcm               110592  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    86016  36 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
drm                   360448  13 radeon,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hp_wireless            16384  0
hp_accel               28672  0
button                 16384  1 i915
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
video                  40960  1 i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 radeon,i915
ac                     16384  0
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    45056  3 tpm_infineon,tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
parport_pc             28672  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  585728  1
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  0
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
mbcache                16384  2 ext4
sd_mod                 45056  5
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
mmc_core              147456  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
crc32c_intel           24576  2
aesni_intel           167936  7
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
psmouse               135168  0
libata                249856  2 ahci,libahci
ehci_pci               16384  0
ehci_hcd               81920  1 ehci_pci
xhci_pci               16384  0
xhci_hcd              188416  1 xhci_pci
i2c_i801               24576  0
i2c_smbus              16384  1 i2c_i801
scsi_mod              225280  3 sd_mod,libata,sg
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
usbcore               249856  9 uvcvideo,usbhid,snd_usb_audio,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,snd_usbmidi_lib,btusb,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
mfd_core               16384  2 lpc_ich,rtsx_pci
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
thermal                20480  0
fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: Esta pregunta no es sobre programación.

Comment: Hola @jpangamarca. Creería yo que al editar los archivos de configuración de un sistema operativo, estás programando.... adicionalmente, el ordenador se necesita para programar! Sabes entonces donde puedo hacer esa pregunta? Gracias!

Comment: Esta pregunta estaría mejor en ServerFault o SuperUser (y editar un archivo de configuración no es programación en sí). Deberías además indicar *lo que ya has hecho para intentar para solucionar el problema*.

Comment: Esas solo están en ingles! Pero dale, gracias por tu "VALIOSA" ayuda!

Comment: Lamento no poder solucionarte el problema (no es obligación de nadie aquí, por cierto... bájale un poquito al tono por favor), pero lo que sí es obligación de todos es mantener relevante el contenido del sitio. Saludos.

Comment: @JONATHANOSORIO, te recomiendo no usar mayúsculas: de internet: `En el lenguaje del Internet, escribir en MAYÚSCULA SOSTENIDA es entendido como un grito para llamar la atención.`.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta pregunta estaría mejor en ServerFault o SuperUser.

Comment: Esta pregunta no tendria que ser cerrada basandose en -> ServerFault o SuperUser se puede mirar estos link del meta, por ejemplo este http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174/propuesta-sitio-tipo-serverfault-o-superuser en el cual Juan M cometa o en este otro por Konamiman http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio .Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Pues igual, si su temática no pertenece a la del sitio, no debería estar aquí. Si estamos metidos en esto del desarrollo de software se supone que tenemos un nivel aceptable (no necesariamente bueno o excelente) de dominio del idioma inglés, que nos permita preguntar en otros sitios. Si me preguntas, ni siquiera estoy de acuerdo con la existencia de versiones de StackOverflow en idiomas aparte del inglés, porque fragmentan el conocimiento, y después de todo, el inglés es la *lingua franca* del Internet, ¿no? Pero en todo caso existen, y sirven de beneficio a la comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

Edita el fichero **/etc/network/interfaces** para añadir lo siguiente:

```
con dhcp
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

sin dhcp
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # Tu dirección IP
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # Tu máscara de red
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # Tu puerta de enlace
```

Además, si estás en el segundo caso (sin *DHCP*) deberás configurar los servidores de nombres (*DNS*). Añade una línea así: `nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` por cada servidor de nombres que quieras configurar en el fichero **/etc/resolv.conf**.

Todos éstos datos te los debe dar tu proveedor, si no sabes alguno llama al servicio de atención al cliente y te los proporcionarán.

Una vez editado todo, procede a levantar la interfaz de red tecleando `ifup eth0`. **No** será necesario teclear ésto en las próximas ocasiones ya que la línea `auto eth0` hace que el sistema levante la interfaz `eth0` al iniciarse.

Comment: Hola @Faty Macías, ya lo hice y no me funciona. Mira como quedo mi archivo interfaces:
"# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp
"
Cuando ejecuto 'ifup eth0', me responde: 'ifup: no se encontró la orden'. Pensé que era permisos y lo ejecuté con 'SUDO' pero me dice lo mismo! Quedo atento!